# AngularJs Directive: How to dynamically set attributes on ng-repeat element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jqlite

I am relatively new to AngularJS. While venturing into directive creation, I can across this problem:  **How to dynamically add / remove attributes on the children of the directive's element when these children are dynamically added with 'ng-repeat'?**

First, I thought of this solution:

**template**

```
...
a.list-group-item(ng-repeat='playlist in playlists', ng-click='addToPlaylist(playlist, track)', ng-href='playlist/{{ playlist._id }})
...
```

***directive**

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {   
  var listItems = angular.element(element[0].getElementsByClassName('list-group-item')
  angular.forEach(listItems, function(item, index) {
    'add' in attrs ? item.removeAttr('href') : item.removeAttr('ng-click');
    listItems[index] = item;
  }
...
```

**Result**

It turns out, my code never enters this `angular.forEach` loop because listItems is empty. I suppose it's because the `ng-repeat` is waiting for the scope.playlists to populate with the data from a async call to a server via $resource.

**temporary fix**

in the directive definition, I added a boolean variable that checks for the presence of 'add' in the element's attributes: `var adding = 'add' in attrs ? true : false;`

And then in the template,

```
a.list-group-item(ng-if='adding', ng-repeat='playlist in playlists', ng-click='addToPlaylist(playlist, track)')
a.list-group-item(ng-if='!adding', ng-repeat='playlist in playlists', ng-href='playlist/{{playlist._id }}')
```

While it works fine, it is obviously not DRY at all. HELP!

Comment: Your final solution is not that bad at all actually, although it seems repetitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing attributes, change your click handler.

Add `$event` to the list of arguments and conditionally use `preventDefault()`.

```
<a ng-click='addToPlaylist($event,playlist)' ng-href='playlist'>CLICK ME</a>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.addToPlaylist = function(event,playlist) {
     if (!$scope.adding) return;
     //otherwise
     event.preventDefault();
     //do add operation
};
```

When not adding, the function returns and the href is fetched. Otherwise the default is prevented and the click handler does the add operation.

From the Docs:

> ### $event
>
> Directives like `ngClick` and `ngFocus` expose a `$event` object within the scope of that expression. The object is an instance of a [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) when jQuery is present or a similar jqLite object.

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide -- $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. It works like a charm and solve the problem in a DRY way. Thanks!

Comment: Not only is the solution DRY. It solves your problem **without** writing a custom directive. You can achieve what you want using the built-in directives. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 2):

The way that you are trying to do things may not be the most Angularish (Angularist? Angularyist?) way. When using `angular.element()` to select child elements as you are trying to do here, you can make sure the child elements are ready as follows:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
  elm.ready(function() {
    var listItems = angular.element(element[0].getElementsByClassName('list-group-item')
    angular.forEach(listItems, function(item, index) {
      'add' in attrs ? item.removeAttr('href') : item.removeAttr('ng-click');
      listItems[index] = item;
    }
  });
}
```

However, this is unlikely to work in your situation, as [@charlietfl points out below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375105/angularjs-directive-how-to-dynamically-set-attributes-on-ng-repeat-element/35375280?noredirect=1#comment58457044_35375280). If you want to avoid the solution you already have (which I think is better than your first attempt), you will have to reimplement your code altogether.

I would suggest defining an additional directive that [communicates with its parent directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate) using the `require` property of the directive definition object. The new directive would have access to an `add` property of the parent (`this.add` in the parent directive's *controller*) and could be programmed to behave accordingly. The implementation of that solution is beyond the scope of this answer.

### Update:

I decided to give the implementation something of a shot. The example is highly simplified, but it does what you are trying to do: alter the template of a directive based on the attributed passed to it. See the example [here](http://codepen.io/akim-mcmath/pen/xZMPjj).

The example uses a new feature in Angular 1: [components](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/guide/component). You can read more about injectable templates and components [here](https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method). Essentially, components allow you to define templates using a function with access to your element and its attributes, like so:

```
app.component('playlistComponent', {

    // We can define out template as a function that returns a string:
    template: function($element, $attrs) {
      var action = 'add' in $attrs
        ? 'ng-click="$ctrl.addToPlaylist(playlist, track)"'
        : 'ng-href="playlist/{{playlist._id}}"';

      return '<a class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" ' +
        action + '></a>';
    },

    // Components always use controllers rather than scopes
    controller: ['playlistService', function(playlists) {
      this.playlists = playlists;

      this.addToPlaylist = function(playlist, track) {
        // Some logic
      };
    }]
  });
```

Comment: explanation doesn't make sense. Angular doesn't bootstrap until dom is ready and directive can't fire unless element exists. Perception of how `ready` works is inaccurate. Repeating elements as children are a different situation

Comment: @charlietfl Would you be able to edit the answer to correct it or maybe provide a better one? I probably phrased things inaccurately, but I think the solution will work. I'll try to rephrase, but feel free to edit if I'm still not getting it right.

Comment: Whole question seems like "chicken before the egg". Doesn't make sense at all to loop over the repeating dom nodes in the first place

Comment: @charlietfl OK, I agree. That's why I suggested an alternative, although this would require a completely different implementation.

Comment: There  are cases (like certain plugins or height equalizers) that do require looping the DOM nodes. Easiest way i know is to check for `$last` within repeated child scopes and use that to trigger dom search

Comment: However I don't think removing `ng-click` attribute will work anyway after it has already been compiled ... wouldn't remove event listener on element

Comment: @McMath: Thanks a lot for your input. I will read more about Angular components and test your approach. Thanks again.